# Php Exec with Shell Script

Tags: php, shell, exec

I have a script.sh with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
    echo You Name:
    read name
    echo You Age:
    read age
    echo Name: $name, Age: $age.
```

Is it possible to pass the name and age variables to the read shell script with php?

Comment: are tou created your .sh file using php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can Pass parameters to bash.

PHP:

```
$output = exec("./bashscript $name $age");

#!/bin/bash
```

Bash:

```
name=$1
age=$2
```

Reference: [passing a variable from php to bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460645/passing-a-variable-from-php-to-bash)