# Parameter passing from PHP to shell

Tags: php, shell, parameter-passing

Is it possible to pass parameters from **php** to a **shell** script.
For ex:

```
<?php

$var = "testfolder";

shell_exec('sh /path/test.sh');

?>
```

Shell script (**test.sh**):

```
sudo mkdir $var /path/
```

I want the value in php `$var` to be exported to the shell script to be able to create a folder with the name as in the variable.
Is this possible?

I know already how to insert a variable into a string, but i can't figure out how to rewrite the line `shell_exec` to export this variable to my shell script

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What you pass to `shell_exec()` is just an ordinary string. Just concatenate or use variable interpolation like you would on any other string.

Comment: How can i edit this line to pass the value **$var** ?

Comment: String interoplation (double quotes): `"mkdir $var"`. Concatenation: `'mkdir ' . $var`. Pick your favorite. You should also [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) about strings in PHP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - concatenate or directly insert variables in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605965/php-concatenate-or-directly-insert-variables-in-string)

Comment: Thanks i understood how to insert `$var` into my string with the above link. But i can't figure out how to rewrite the line `shell_exec` in order to export the variable `$var` to my shell script.

Comment: How about `shell_exec("foo $var bar")` or `shell_exec('foo ' . $var . ' bar')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the variable as a command line parameter to the shell script.  For example:

```
<?php
$var = "testfolder";
echo 'php: ' . shell_exec("sh ./test.sh $var");
```

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "shell: $1"
```

```
$ php test.php
php: shell: testfolder
```

(For clarity, I'm simply echoing here.)

Shells transform command line parameters sequentially into variables `$1`, `$2`, etc.

Comment: `$1` is storing `php: testfolder ` . How can i remove the `php: `? I need only the `testfolder` .

Comment: Remove `'php: ' .` from the echo

Answer (score 2):

Yes.You need to pass the variables as arguments to the shell script, and the shell script has to read its arguments.

please check this link: [passing a variable from php to bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19460645/passing-a-variable-from-php-to-bash)